# discordjs move user to specific channel after press reaction (not voice channel)

Tags: javascript, discord, move, roles, channel

how can i move the user to a another channel. (not a voice channel)

here is my code in the index.js

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
  if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
  if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
  if (user.bot) return;
  if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

  // TR
  if (reaction.message.channel.id == "1129857569003937803") {


    if (reaction.emoji.name === "ws") {
    
  
      await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(["1127642705456009326", "1128261558598893640"]);
      await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(["1129829277416837130", "1129823658362273892"]);

    }
  }
});
```

when the roles deleted the user stays on the same channel .